# Android Studio Sending SMS with SQLite data

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app that stores the users input(name and phone number) and then I want to be able to access the given phone number, and send an automated SMS when user clicks on a button. I am not sure how to approach accessing the database to input the phone number, I already setup the buttons to add information into the database. I just need to figure out how to pull the numbers entered and send SMS to them with a click of a button. Below is my `DBHelper.java`:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Userdata.db",null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB) {

        DB.execSQL("Create Table Userdetails(name TEXT primary key, contact TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase DB, int i, int i1) {

        DB.execSQL("drop Table if exists Userdetails");

    }

    public Boolean insertuserdata(String name, String contact){

        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name",name);
        contentValues.put("contact",contact);
        long result = DB.insert("Userdetails",null,contentValues);
        if(result ==-1){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Boolean updateuserdata(String name, String contact) {

        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("contact", contact);
        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from Userdetails where name = ?", new String[]{name});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            long result = DB.update("Userdetails", contentValues, "name=?", new String[]{name});
            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   

    public Boolean deleteuserdata(String name) {

        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from Userdetails where name = ?", new String[]{name});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            long result = DB.delete("Userdetails", "name=?", new String[]{name});
            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }


        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getdata() {

        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from Userdetails", null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the code you've posted,  I presume you are able to write to and read from the database? If so, is your question actually about using a phone number to send an SMS? All of your posted code is database logic.

Comment: Define a `where` clause to filter the phone numbers.